# Preventing duplicates before insert in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to add(or insert) row after selecting one, but first i need to check if what i am adding isn't duplicate, every time i enter two values that are the same i achieving strange results, i was using `foreach` and now `for` statement but none of these helped me:

```
        private void plus()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("duple");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim(), pictureBox3.Image, pictureBox6.Image);
                break;
            }
        }
        textBox1.SelectAll();
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to insert every iteration.
Insertion should be at the end of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("duple");
        return;
    }
}

dataGridView2.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim(), pictureBox3.Image, pictureBox6.Image);
```

Comment: well after the message box pops up, it still add it to the datagridview!, how to prevent that

Comment: replace `break` with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is if text is not match with row text it will add text to grid without searching full grid. Also recommended use cell name instead of cell index.

```
    private void plus()
    {
        bool IsDuplicate = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {
                IsDuplicate = true;
                MessageBox.Show("duple");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!IsDuplicate)
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim(), pictureBox3.Image, pictureBox6.Image);

        textBox1.SelectAll();
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS CODE ... YOU NEED TO EMPTY THE DATA SET 
  when working with datagridview and data binding

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Table", connexion);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
ds.Clear();
da.Fill(ds, "Your Dataset here");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score -2):

# CREARE A  STATIC LISTBOX OR LIST<> AND USE THIS CODE I USED IT TO STORE MULTIPLE DATA ..

```
 if (!listBox5.Items.Contains(id + "-" + pass + "-" + room + "-" + remoter + "-" + roompass))
     {
         listBox5.Items.Add(id + "-" + pass + "-" + room + "-" + remoter + "-" + roompass);
         Console.WriteLine("NOT THERE ");

         form1.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, id, pass, room, remoter, roompass);
     }
```